# Customization of Alfresco for Postgres and Autoscaling

Tags: amazon-web-services, chef-infra, alfresco, aws-cloudformation

We're building out a custom Alfresco deployment on AWS and are using Alfresco's CloudFormation template as a framework.  Unfortunately, there's little documentation for our requirement of rolling with Aurora Postgres (as opposed to Aurora MySQL) and how the adjustments impact the AMI's and autoscaling which appear to be managed via undocumented chef scripts.

I was hoping someone may have traveled this road before and could provide some guidance.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are more likely to get more interaction on community.alfresco.com

Comment: Autoscaling the DB or autoscaling the Alfresco nodes?

Comment: @JeffPotts - Alfresco nodes

Comment: @YounesRegaieg - Agreed... cross posting